# How to know what vertices need split according to normals?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I'm trying to implement addon that will show the real vertex count.
But i can't understand how to decide what vertices to count and which not to count.

I create new mesh, triangulate it and then do

```
calc_normals
calc_normals_split
calc_tessface
```

so i think after this i have all the required info somewhere in mesh data. in polygons.normals or tessface.normals i dunno..

Appeared that i lack knowledge about low level 3d graphics.

As a test i'm using this thingy:

[image]

It has 42 triangles, 240 total vertices (if all the faces would be flat-shaded) and 146 vertices when it has half of the faces smoothed.

I tried checking use_smooth variable on polygons and tessfaces, but it always returns True.

Could someone advice where to look? Or may be there is already such addon?

UPD:
found interesting thing:

[image]

here vertex-per-face normals of flat-shaded face represented by 5 lines, and for smooth-shaded face by single line.

i thought that i could get this info from split-normals of tessfaces, but failed. normals having 0.0 are 315, which divided by 3 is 105. if i substact 105 from 240 i will get only 35, but i need 146.

so where can i get these zero normals, that are shown by single line?

Comment: Actually i've managed to write the addon: https://github.com/curly-brace/Blender-Vertex-Counter

Comment: What do you need these numbers for? The values as calculated by blender feel very real to me.